# How can I resolve this message: "Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: CentALT. Please verify its path and try again"?

Tags: linux, centos, rpm

When running this CentOS 6:

```
yum update
```

I get this:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security   
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.bytemark.co.uk
 * extras: mirror.mhd.uk.as44574.net
 * updates: mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net
http://centos.alt.ru/repository/centos/6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: CentALT. Please verify its path and try again
```

How can I resolve that?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem adding chromium.repo file. I am using RH 6.6. I commented out url line and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The yum server seems can not be reached, try another mirror or check your internet connection first.

Comment: Connection is fine, and the message says "Trying other mirror." before erroring. Is there a list of mirrors I should set somewhere in config?

Comment: Check your DNS first, then modify your /etc/yum.repos.d/[anyname_can_be].repo change the "baseurl"   line to a proper server. Then run yum clean;yum list to see if it works.